# How to make a custom bash tab completion?

Tags: bash, autocomplete

I want to make tab completion to complete on specific programs in path although there maybe other possible completion in path.

For example, if I type `mpl` and <kbd>tab</kbd>, it should complete to mplayer though there might be other programs in the path starting with `mpl`. I know of bash alias builtin for `~/.bashrc` but thats not what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

If you've installed the bash-completion package it includes everything you need in the way of examples. I'd look through any of the included files as examples. The `ntpdate` one is pretty basic.

```
$ less /etc/bash_completion.d/ntpdate
$ less /usr/share/bash-completion/ntpdate
```